# Using WHERE with JOIN & GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table structure:

**teams**

```
  t_id     => int(11)
  t_name   => varchar(256)
```

**sales**

```
  s_id     => int(11)
  s_amount => int(11)
  s_date   => date
  team_id  => int(11)
```

I want to summarize all sales for a specific period of time for a all teams. This is my SQL-Command:

```
SELECT 
    t_name,
    SUM(s_amount) as total_amount,

    FROM teams 

    JOIN sales ON sales.team_id=teams.t_id
    GROUP BY sales.team_id

    WHERE s_date BETWEEN '2013-09-01' 
    AND '2013-09-08';
```

If i exec this command in phpmyadmin it says:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE s_date BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND '2013-09-08' L' at line 10
```

**What am i doing wrong here?**

Comment: Please avoid the use of `BETWEEN` - [the article here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) details some problems when dealing with date/time/timestamp types (some of which are SQL Server specific).  Although as you're likely dealing with 'business days' in this context, it's not as likely to bite you.  Still, nearly all ranges should use exclusive upper-bounds (`<`), especially for types that do, or can be used with, varying precisions (essentially, all measurements, including money, weight, length, etc).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse The keyword `BETWEEN` is missleading, yes, but luckily it does the exact thing what i wanted it to do here. In the future i will remember your comment and use `<` & `>`

Comment: No, actually, you usually want to use _inclusive_ **lower bounds** (`>=`).  For example: Shipping packages by weight.  Ranges are usually on an 'integer' amount (say, 3 pounds, next is at 5 pounds, etc).  However, the scales measure to some fraction of this, and updating stored range boundaries to deal with varying levels of accuracy is not an option; essentially, you run into the milliseconds problem.  If something is not an integer count (and even then...), it needs to be handled as though it can have actual, infinite precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order is wrong

```
SELECT 
t_name,
SUM(s_amount) as total_amount

FROM teams 

JOIN sales ON sales.team_id=teams.t_id
WHERE s_date BETWEEN '2013-09-01' 
AND '2013-09-08'
GROUP BY sales.team_id;
```

Where goes before GROUP BY:

> 1.SELECT clause
>
> 2.FROM clause
>
> 3.WHERE clause
>
> 4.GROUP BY clause
>
> 5.HAVING clause
>
> 6.ORDER BY clause

([this article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm) seems to be a good one, except that for quick parsing, the order seems to be wrong, as it is listed for optimization preference of the author. In that regards, it is a good one. But for copying and pasting the list to visualilze the order of the clauses it is not :) )

Comment: chek the comma after `total_amount`

Comment: @StuartLC: thanks for spotting, CtrlC-CtrlV and too low quality pattern matching result in errors...

Comment: Re : From before select - was from the linked article like that FWR. Logically it might be good to think in this way, i.e. the map / projection done quite late (e.g. the .Net Linq query syntax perpetuates this), but I guess the RDBMS wants the select up front :)

Comment: The article lists the clauses in the order of **logical** processing, not how the queries are written.

Comment: I am an idiot: I assumed there was a misorder in my code and then i looked into the mysql (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) reference manual. Then i rearranged my code to given order ... but i failed at that point. Thanks for the help

Comment: @BastiFunck we all make mistakes - even sillier ones :) (like copying a list from an article, without properly looking at it)

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE` clause should be before `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
t_name,
SUM(s_amount) as total_amount    
FROM teams    
JOIN sales ON sales.team_id=teams.t_id
WHERE s_date BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND '2013-09-08'
GROUP BY sales.team_id;
```

Comment: Same error of @ppeterka 66, check the comma after `total_amount`.